# How to set locale in controller

Tags: silverstripe

In my SilverStripe project I have a controller which I call by a cronjob. But in this controller I want to use the translations from the yaml language files. So I want to set the locale to use the right translations. I tried to do something like this, but this doesn't work:

```
class CronController extends Controller {

public function opendataform() {

    i18n::set_locale('it_IT');

    $Params = $this->getURLParams();
    self::$ad = $Params['ID'];
    $selectMemberSelectionField = new DropdownField('SelectionName', _t('General.CHOOSE_SELECTION', "Choose selection"), MemberSelection::get()->map('ID', 'Name'));
    $fields = new FieldList($selectMemberSelectionField);

    $actions = new FieldList(
        FormAction::create("doOpen")->setTitle(_t('General.Open', "Open"))
    );

    $form = new Form($this, 'OpenForm', $fields, $actions);
    return $form;

}
}
```

Also tried with: Translatable::set_current_locale('it_IT');

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance!

Comment: `set_locale` should work. Are you sure your translations are in place and did you do `dev/build?flush=1`?

Comment: The character case in the label didn't match, now it works with set_locale indeed. Feeling a bit stupid... :( Thanks bummzack!

Comment: @brasileric you should post your fix as an answer and accept it.